# Fitting a 2D Ellipse to points

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to fit an ellipse to a scatter plot. The code I'm using is below

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Xi and Yi are arrays with my X and Y coordinates of points

    # Transform into columns
    X = np.c_[Xi]
    Y = np.c_[Yi]

    # Solve the least squares problem
    A = np.hstack([X**2, X * Y, Y**2, X, Y])
    b = np.ones_like(X)
    x = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)[0].squeeze()

    # Plot the data
    x_coord = np.linspace(-5,5,300)
    y_coord = np.linspace(-5,5,300)
    X_coord, Y_coord = np.meshgrid(x_coord, y_coord)
    Z_coord = x[0] * X_coord ** 2 + x[1] * X_coord * Y_coord + x[2] * Y_coord**2 + x[3] * X_coord + x[4] * Y_coord
    plt.contour(X_coord, Y_coord, Z_coord, levels=[1], colors=('r'), linewidths=2)
    plt.show()
```

The problem is, sometimes, the best fit is an hyperbola, instead of an ellipse, since they have the same formula `Ax² + Bxy + Cy² + Dx + Ey + F = 0`. Is there any way I can change my `A` matrix to make sure that I'm always getting an ellipse?

Comment: Can you post sample `X` and `Y`?

Comment: I think you mean an ellipse?

Comment: Look at Wikipedia [Conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant).

Comment: Take a look at @JeanJacquelin's paper on the subject: [Régressions coniques, quadriques, circulaire, sphérique](https://www.scribd.com/document/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique). I'll start translating that one one I've completed the one on [Régressions et équations intégrales](https://www.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales) (currently on a bit of a hiatus).